# (C++) How to pass around a pointer to an object allocated with 'new' from function to function without causing a mem leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, scope, heap-memory

I am working on a project meant to understand **memory management** using C++,

Inside a function, if I create a new array of Student objects, do function stuff, and then return a pointer to the array like so:

```
int main(){

    Student *ptr = new newStudents[50];
    Student p.FunctionCall(ptr);
    //stuff
    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;

}
```

I will then instantiate the object (make a copy) in main, and other class methods perhaps too, taking care to call `delete[]` after every usage.

*Will it cause a memory leak to pass the heap pointer from function back into main and or other funcs as long as I remember to call delete from the last place it existed?*

*Constraints*: no smart pointers, no namespace and no C++ 11 or higher.

It's for an assignment. All help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us in the question.

Comment: There is arguably very, very little point in using C++ if you are not allowed to use namespaces and smart pointers. The code in your question is pretty much C, except for the use of the `new` statement. Btw, `class *x` looks wrong. And you are missing semicolon at the end of statements.

Comment: ok Marc I fixed the semicolons so you feel more comfortable. And the point is learning memory management and building a ground up knowledge of how languages function. So do you have any help to contribute?

Comment: Thanks. Note that, in spite of being a little "direct", I had no intention to be rude or to come across as all-knowing. I wanted to point out something that should be of use  not only to you, but other readers as well. As for the semicolons etc, it is helpful for others to answer your question when it includes code that actually compiles. Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, it is advisable to assume good intentions. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be:

```
MyClass* function(const char* file) {
    MyClass *x = new MyClass[50];  //class_type* array_name = new class_type[amount];

    //stuff to parse values and then instantiate my classes

    return x;  // return x directly as a pointer..
}
```

First.. Do NOT dereference the pointer you got from `new` and return it, because it's not a pointer to a pointer or pointer to an instance. It's literally a pointer to memory of an array and by dereferencing it, you will be returning an instance and losing the rest.. resulting in a leak.

So with that your of the way, you can now do:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass* array = function("some_file.txt");
    // do something with the array above..
    delete[] array;  //clean up..
}
```

Comment: Okay _thank you_ that solution looks clean and keeps my reference in main which is ideal.

Comment: @amorphous_solid; It's fixed. It was a typo as I was trying to add comments, I accidentally typed it there. :) you cannot ever do `new new`. It would be a syntax error. Thanks for noticing it. Should be good now :)

Comment: When you use the argument const char* file is that the same as passing the text file in the parameter? Must I have an argument there or just leave it empty parenthese as long as the return type matches the function type?

Comment: @amorphous_solid; `const char*` is a const array of characters.. IE: a string.. So you pass in the path to the file.. Example: `"some_file.txt"` or `"/users/brandon/desktop/some_file.txt"` or w/e.. There is code in the `main` function that is using it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
char* allocate_buffer() {
    return new char[10];
}

int main() {
    auto buf = allocate_buffer();
    delete [] buf;
}
```

No memory leaks. You should use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of managing memory manually.

Comment: What about: ```char* allocate_buffer() {
    Class *ptr =  new classArray[10]; return ptr;
}

```

Comment: Obviously you need to change the type names, but it will work regardless of the types of your variables.

Comment: But will the memory leak doing this? That's the question

Comment: @amorphous_solid It will leak if you don't free the memory.

Comment: @iz_ ... or if something happens between the allocation and free statements that prevent the free'ing of being executed (exceptions are notorious for doing this).

Comment: @amorphous_solid The type doesn't matter, as long as you call `delete []` on the buffer at some point it will be freed and won't leak.

Comment: @Marc.2377 what is the point of replying to someone who isn't even asking the question my guy?. Do you have anything that isn't grossly superior to say or what ... you're not helping out .

Comment: @iz_ could you provide me an example of a viable parameter for a function that would return the type I need (that isn't a char- something with a std::string)

Comment: I don't see how @Marc.2377 was being rude; he was adding information to the conversation. As for *"a viable parameter for a function that would return the type I need"*, I have no idea what you mean by that. A function's arguments have nothing to do with its return type. In this case, your function doesn't even need arguments. For your own type, just use the answer's code and replace `char` with whatever you need.

Comment: @Ayjay "*the type doesn't matter*" - not true. The type of pointer passed to `delete[]` needs to be the same type of pointer that `new[]` returned, or at least compatible with it in the case of polymorphism. Allocating an array of objects, converting that array pointer to a `char*` pointer, and then calling `delete[]` on that `char*` pointer, will not destroy the objects correctly. Which will cause leaks if the objects own memory/resources they are responsible for freeing.

Comment: "whatever I need" .... that's what I don't know. I don't know what type to make the function to return what I need. Ayjay said to make the function type char but I know char isn't what I need @iz_

Comment: @amorphous_solid I'm not sure how I would know what type you need. What are you allocating? An array of `int`? Replace `char` with `int`. An array of `foobarbaz` (some user-defined type)? Replace `char` with `foobarbaz`.